# Is there a way to perform edit distance between two string columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, data-science, edit-distance

I have two datasets: dataset1 & dataset2 (image link provided), which have a common column called `SAX` which is a string object.

```
dataset1=
         SAX
0    glngsyu
1    zicobgm
2    eerptow
3    cqbsynt
4    zvmqben
..       ...
475  rfikekw
476  bnbzvqx
477  rsuhgax
478  ckhloio
479  lbzujtw

480 rows × 2 columns
```

and

```
dataset2=
         SAX
0    glngsyu
1    zicobgm
2    eerptow
3    cqbsynt
4    zvmqben
..       ...
475  rfikekw
476  bnbzvqx
477  rsuhgax
478  ckhloio
479  lbzujtw

480 rows × 2 columns
```

I need the output to be a column of minimum number of edits (operations) required to convert "SAX" column of dataset1 to "SAX" of dataset2. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Comment: By `edit-distance` you mean Levenshtein distance?

Comment: @Daweo- yes I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Levenshtein distance from the [textdistance](https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/) module:

```py
from textdistance import levenshtein

# Merge the two columns in one dataframe
df = dataset1[['SAX']].merge(dataset2[['SAX']], left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_1', '_2'))

# Compute the Levenshtein distance
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: levenshtein.distance(x['SAX_1'],  x['SAX_2']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pylev](https://pypi.org/project/pylev/) module for this task. It is pure-python so it should work in any operating system just after doing `pip install pylev`. For comparison of pair-wise elements I would harness `zip`, consider following simple example

```
import pylev
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['some','values','here']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['same','virtues','there']})
dfdist = pd.DataFrame({'dist':[pylev.levenshtein(*i) for i in zip(df1.col1,df2.col1)]})
print(dfdist)
```

output

```
   dist
0     1
1     3
2     1
```